# Check if all elements in 2d array are equal (Ruby)

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

Through snooping around on here, I've defined the current method for testing if an array of unknown size contains matching elements;

```
def matching_elements? array
array.uniq.length == 1
end
```

I was trying to extend this to cover a 2d array of unknown size using the following;

```
def all_elements_identical? array
array.each { |subarray| matching_elements?(subarray) }
end
```

The above returns `true/false` for each subarray, but I'm having a hard time thinking of a way to use the results of the combined methods in a conditional statement. I'd like to do things based on whether the 2d array contains matching elements or not, so for a 'test' array, both of the following would need to be true

```
matching_elements?(test)
all_elements_identical?(test)
```

Here's the code I've been using, with the 'putsing' just in place to confirm to me that the methods are doing what I intend, but I don't know how to translate that returned info into a conditional statement, indicated by the brackets in the code comment;

```
test = [[2,2,2,2,2,2],
        [2,2,2,2,2,2],
        [2,2,2,2,2,2],
        [2,2,2,2,2,2],
        [2,2,2,2,2,2],
        [2,2,2,2,2,2],
        [2,2,2,2,2,2]]

def is_identical? array
array.uniq.length == 1
end

def all_identical? array
array.each { |subarray| puts is_identical?(subarray)} 
end

print "Primary array contains matching elements? "
puts is_identical?(test)
puts "Subarrays each contain matching elements?"
all_identical?(test)

=begin
  if (2d elements are all identical) == true
    "YAY"
  end
=end
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Update and provide an example of a test case.  Otherwise why can't you just use the ` == ` comparison operator i.e. `array_a == array_b` ?

Comment: hi @lacostenycoder - just updated the post, hope that's clearer. Not sure how I'd use the comparison operator in this case... any tips?

Comment: All you need is `arr.flatten.uniq.size == 1` for any level of array nesting.

Comment: good to know, thanks @CarySwoveland - edited!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing it, but it is the best idea I could think of:

```
def all_elements_identical? array
    matching_elements? array.flatten
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To check one dimension array, as you already did:

```
test[0].uniq.size == 1
```

To check 2D array, do the same:

```
test.uniq.size == 1
```

Or

```
test.all? { |e| e == test.first }
```

Comment: `test.all?` has the virtue of returning as soon as  one element  is defferent.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything more than this simple 1 liner

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]].uniq.count == 1 #=> true

[[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]].uniq.count == 1 #=> false
```